# Performing Variable Expansion in bash without performing Command Substitution

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

How to perform Variable Expansion (Parameter Expansion) on a string in bash without performing Command Substitution at the same time ?

Example: `V=variable C=poweroff S='We have $V and $($C)'`

I'm seeking a bash command/script that, when given `"$S"` as input, produces
`We have variable and $(poweroff)` as output (without powering the machine off).

Edit: This shall work not only with hand-crafted strings but in a generic way with any string, whether it contains variable references or not.

Comment: Maybe `S="We have $V and \$($C)"; echo "$S"` ?

Comment: @AndreWildberg, this shall work not only with hand-crafted strings but in a generic way with any string. Edited the question.

Comment: This is what `envsubst` is for.

Comment: (so in your use case, it'd be `V=variable C=poweroff S=$(envsubst <<<'We have $V and $($C)')`)

Comment: or `export V C; envsubst '$V $C' <<<"$S"` to ignore other variables

Comment: @jhnc, ...that said, exporting two variables _and leaving them in the environment even after envsubst is finished_ is not exactly parsimonious. (Context for other readers: `k=v somecommand` sets `k` in the environment with value `v` while running `somecommand`, but _doesn't_ leave it in the environment after `somecommand` is finished).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, there's better ways of writing what I intended to show - using the format argument to limit which variables get replaced

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, `V=variable C=poweroff S='We have $V and $($C)' envsubst <<< "$S"` is exactly what I want. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Juergen, the question is closed as duplicative (so I can't add an answer here), and I believe we have preexisting answers on the linked duplicate that already cover everything in my comment (if that _weren't_ true, it would be appropriate to add such an answer on the duplicate itself).

Comment: @jhnc, in this case, I asked for a generic variable expansion so I didn't want to limit which variables get replaced.